# Converting recursion to iterations to loops

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to figure out a way to convert the last line of the top most function to iteration using some form of loop rather than recursion. I'm actually stumped right now and I'm wondering if any of you guys can help. It's a function created to search if the given start and ending point path exists within a directed graph using a depth first traversal.

```
def helper(graph, current, visited):
    if current in graph:
        for neighbor in graph[current]:
            if neighbor not in visited:
                visited.append( neighbor )
                helper(graph, neighbor, visited)

def DFS(graph, start, goal):
    if start not in graph and goal not in graph:
        return False
    visited = [start]
    helper(graph, start, visited)
    return goal in visited
```

Comment: There are quite a few things you can find when you search for "tree recursion to iterative" and similar. [Here is one example in Python](http://blog.nextgenetics.net/?e=64). Your graph isn't a tree, but it may be close enough to be helpful. (Search also for "recursion to iteration", without the tree of graph keyword.)